# Same form on page; only one works

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to debug my front-end of a HTML/PHP web face and have run into an issue. Currently, the user is able to upload a file, which is then sent to a separate upload function (to process and upload their file to an AWS instance), and then redirects the user to another page.

On the page, I have two options for the user to click- the first of which unhides an option for the user to select and upload their file. This option uploads to the AWS instance and functions normally. The second option unhides some text about download/upload instructions, along with an option for the user to select and upload their file.

Both options do functionally the same thing, with only difference being the second option unhides some text in addition to revealing exactly the same button. Only the first option posts and uploads like normal; the second doesn't upload to the bucket and just returns 'zero' in plain text to the screen. Has anyone experienced anything like this and/or has any advice on how to fix it? Thanks!

Below are the two code snippets for the upload forms:

```
<form id="Site" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div id="file_input"><input id="files" type="file" name="file"/></div>
    <label for="files">SELECT ZIP FILE TO UPLOAD</label>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitSite">
 </form>
```

and the one that doesn't work (exactly the same?)

```
<p> Download Instructions Go Here</p><br>

    <form id="Site" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div id="file_input"><input id="files" type="file" name="file"/></div>
    <label for="files">SELECT ZIP FILE TO UPLOAD</label>
    
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submitSite">
    </form>
```

And the POST function itself is:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['Username'] = '';
    $userID = $userID; // change this to be set in database

    //set progress
    $_SESSION['progress'] = 'upload_section';
'/survey_interface_shared_libraries/progress_emails/store_progress.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submitSite'])) { // upload file
```

Please let me know if you need any further context!

Comment: if both forms are on same page, you cant use same id for multiple elements.

Comment: and on getting data from second form, it tries to get it from first form instead

Comment: Ahh, that's probably it! I think it is trying to get it from the first form. That being said, I changed the form ID and I am still receiving a 'zero' return state.

Comment: can you show your js code, how you try to handle the forms

Comment: I added some additional context including the POST handling! Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to see javascript code